# getArgs expecting [char] instead of [string]

Tags: haskell, io

This code worked fine when it only took first.
I get this error after having added second.

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Char' with actual type 'String'
Expected type: [Char]
Actual type: [String]
In the first argument of `(++)', namely `first'
In the second argument of `(++)', namely `first ++ " " ++ last !! 0'
```

Which makes no sense to me because `getArg` is suppose to produce a list of string.

```
module Main where
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
first <- getArgs
last <- getArgs
putStrLn ("Hello" ++ first ++ last !! 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getArgs` returns a list of string, not a string. You could use it like this:

```
module Main where
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    putStrLn ("Hello" ++ (args !! 0) ++ (args !! 1))
```

Of course, this is only a demonstration of how to use `getArgs`. In real program, you need to make sure you are given enough arguments before you actually use them.

Comment: You should avoid `!!` wherever you can, and instead do something like `do arg0 : arg1 : _ <- getArgs; putStrLn ("Hello" ++ arg0 ++ arg1)`.

Comment: @kosmikus May I ask why?

Comment: `(!!)` takes linear time w.r.t the index, is partial, and if you care about the partiality it induces you to use `length` (which also has linear complexity). Even if you don't care about the partiality using a pattern makes it more obvious to readers that the match might fail.

Comment: @duplode Good point, thank you. The use of `(!!)` in my answer tries to mimic the use of that operator in the original post, I hope that is easier for the asker to understand. So I will keep it for now.

Comment: Can you explain the use of (!!) actually? I realize I don't understand why it is there.

Comment: @user2415706 The result of `getArgs` is a list of string. `lst !! n` will return the `n`th element from list `lst`, starting from zero. If list `lst` has less than `n+1` elements, that function (operator) will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to concatenate "Hello" which is a String to `first` which is a list of Strings.

I also don't understand why you're using getArgs twice. `first == last`.

Comment: `first == last`? Not necessarily! That is why `getArgs` has an IO type in the first place.

Comment: @Ingo I can't think of a way in which this would not be the case for this code. Perhaps if you somehow modified the arguments between the two `getArgs`, but that is not the case.

Comment: You're right in this specific case, unless the code runs in a debugger.

Comment: It works though if the line is just 
putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ args !! 0)
which is what confuses me

I assumed you would put bind the second thing to another getArgs?!

Comment: @user2415706 You have it backwards. You're binding the result of the getArgs computation to some names. If you only use the first one (via args !! 0) you get only the first argument printed after Hello. If you also use (args !! 1) you get the first two arguments, etc.

The result of getArgs should be the same each time you run the computation, because the list of arguments don't (shouldn't) change at runtime.